# When using a foreach loop and a reference, how can I stop the last member pointing to a reference?

Tags: php, reference

Consider this code...

```
$a = range(1, 5);

foreach($a as &$b) { }

var_dump($a);
```

The output is...

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  &int(5)
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/Us4ElSLd).

See the `&` on the last member? How can I stop that?

Answer (score 1):

You can `unset($b)`.

```
$a = range(1, 5);

foreach($a as &$b) { }

unset($b);

var_dump($a);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/9wM5oHDX).

You should `unset()` to avoid this...

```
$a = range(1, 5);

foreach($a as &$b) { }

$b = 10;

var_dump($a);
```

...which outputs...

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  &int(10)
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/ef5O0L5c).